# Sinon JQuery selectors mock

Tags: mocha.js, sinon

I am trying to test a function using mocha/sinonjs. The function I want to test is responsible for showing or hiding some element in my DOM.

This is my function

```
var updateUI = function() {
  $('#login').show();
  $('#logout').hide();
};
```

I tried to mock using sinon but I'm not sure if it is possible or the correct thing to do in this case.

This is what I have tried but I keep getting an error `"TypeError: undefined is not a function"` during the `expect` call

```
 var mockLogin = sinon.mock($);
 mockLogin.withArgs('#login').expects("show").once();
```

I simple want to test my 2 jquery calls have been called. I tried to use spies but continue to get exceptions

Answer (score 3):

Looking further into the sinon doc I found that the following worked for me.

```
var jQueryShow = sinon.stub($.fn, 'show');
var jQueryHide = sinon.stub($.fn, 'hide');

jQueryShow.callCount.should.be.equal(1);
jQueryShow.thisValues[0].selector.should.be.equal("#login");

jQueryHide.callCount.should.be.equal(1);
jQueryHide.thisValues[0].selector.should.be.equal("#logout");
```

I'm not sure if there an easier way but it checks for the selectors I need